# System Error &h80040e14 when running Stored Procedure from VBA to Stored Proc on server

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have an Excel tool that connects to a SQL DB on another server and runs a Stored Procedure.

The connection is done in the `"ConnectDB"` Function, which works.

The problem occurs on this line : `Set objMyRecordset = cmd.Execute`

The error I get is

> System Error &h80040e14

Now Ive googled and it seems to come down to permissions ? And I need to add "Execute" permissions to the stored procedure I am running, but that does nothing.

Anyone have any idea where I am going wrong ? Just to add some extra info, normal Update statements work, but not when trying to execute the Stored Procedure.

Below is my code. The connection to the DB work

```
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command

    Set objMyRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim FilePath As String, DealerType As String

    Progress_Indicator.Show vbModeless
    Progress_Indicator.Repaint

    DealerType = wsStart.Cells(12, 9).Value
    FilePath = wsStart.Cells(14, 9).Value

    ConnectDB

    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = objMyConn
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandText = "sp_Import_And_Calculate_SpareParts_Report_HardCoded"
    '.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@DealerType", adVarChar, adParamInput, 20, DealerType)
    '.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@FilePath", adVarChar, adParamInput, 1000, FilePath)
    .CommandTimeout = 0
    '.Execute
    End With

    Set objMyRecordset = cmd.Execute
```

Comment: You sure you have `Execute` rights to this stored procedure? It must be set by sql server admin.

Comment: I got it to work. Your statement is something I did, amongst many other things, but do think your statement is the reason it worked, as this is the only thing I didnt do previously. So if you post your answer, I will mark as the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sure you have `Execute` rights to this stored procedure? It must be set by sql server admin.